# How to use GDK with Quickly

Tags: python, quickly, resize

I trying to use the library gdk for scale down an image and apply it to a GdkImage.

This is the code
`pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(fileName)
 pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(100, 100, Gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)`

The problem is that python can't find Gdk even if I use everything in lowercase

Error:
pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(fileName)
NameError: global name 'Gdk' is not defined

I don't know what should I do because I tried to import Gdk but nothing is changed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try importing it like this:

```
 from gi.repository import Gtk
 from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf, InterpType
```

then:

```
 pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_file(filename)
 pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(100, 100, InterpType.BILINEAR)
```

I would recommend using the command below because it automatically scales it when it reads it in. Just specify how big (pixels) you want the image to be:

```
 pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(size_x, size_y, filename)
```

- Using **scale_simple()** does **not** preserve aspect ratio.
- Using **new_from_file_at_size()** preserves aspect ratio

Comment: Yes it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your answer almost worked for me, but I got the following errormessage:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gdk' object has no attribute 'INTERP_BILINEAR'
```

But I found the definition of it here [gtkmm:gdkmm Enums and Flags](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.10/group__gdkmmEnums.html):

```
Gdk::InterpType { 
  Gdk::INTERP_NEAREST, 
  Gdk::INTERP_TILES, 
  Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR, 
  Gdk::INTERP_HYPER 
}
```

So for me it worked when I called the function like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf
...
pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_file('mypic.gif')
pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(desired_width, desired_height, 2) # 2 := BILINEAR
```

...maybe this helps someone with the same problem ;)

Comment: Why not edit the answer and solve the problem?